# Can't run npm dev with vue cli webpack-simple

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am installing vuejs following the [github link](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple), i did all steps like it is described, but when i try to run npm dev i have this stacktrace full of errors:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib
npm ERR! floraapp@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; C:\PostgreSQL\9.2\lib ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the floraapp@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the floraapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs floraapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls floraapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! floraapp@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the floraapp@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the floraapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs floraapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls floraapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\backOffice-FloraApp\npm-debug.log
```

my operative system is windows 10, any help appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed?

Comment: npm -> 3.10.10, node -> v6.10.3

Comment: So, based on the error message, the first thing I would try would be updating to the latest version of node.js and npm. Have you tried that?

Comment: did you run `npm install` first? `ENOENT` usually means something doesn't exist.

Comment: i did, and npm install doesn't work too i already did that before

Comment: `npm install` doesn't work? Make sure you're in a proper directory. I guess you're one level above your project.

Comment: sorry npm install works, just the npm run dev doesn't :/

Comment: dunno why already updated everything

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and run `npm run dev`.

Comment: Try replacing  dev in scripts with scripts "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"